# Mule: How to track non-deletable & non-movable files

Tags: java, file, version-control, mule, mule-studio

I have a directory with files that cannot be removed because they are used by other applications or have read only properties. This means that I can't move or delete the files like Mule does as a natural file tracking system. In order to process these files through Mule once they arrive or when they get updated without deleting/moving them from the original directory I need some sort of custom tracking. To do this I think I need to add some rules and be able to track files that are:

- New files
- Processed files
- Updated files

For this, I thought of having a log file in the same directory that would track each file by name and date modified, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this. I would need to be able to write and read this log file and compare its content with current files in the directory in order to determine which files are new or updated. This seems to be a bit too complicated and requires me to add quite a bit of programming (maybe as groovy scripts or overriding some methods).

Is there any other simpler way to do this on Mule? If not, how should I start tackling this problem? I'm guessing I can write some java to talk to File EndPoint.

Comment: What do you want to do with non-deletable files? Process them just one time? Process them when they change?

Comment: I'm looking to Process them once they arrive at the directory and when they get updated.

Comment: Consider disable auto delete and move to, and then use an idempotent filter with an id expression returning a combination of filename and last update.

Comment: Victor, thank you!. Idempotent Filter actually worked for me, however I'm trying to save the state of the processed files using simple-text-file-store in a file. This works as long as I don't reset the mule process. If I restart the process it ignores the content of the file and re-process every file once again. I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Victor Romero pointed out, Idempotent Filter does the trick. I tried two types of Idempotent Filter to see which one works best: [Idempotent Message Filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-IdempotentMessageFilter)  and [Idempotent Secure Hash Message Filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-IdempotentSecureHashMessageFilter). Both of them did the job, however I ended up using Idempotent Message Filter (no Hash) to log timestamp and filename in the simple-text-file-store.

Just after the File inbound-endpoint:

```
<idempotent-message-filter idExpression="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename+'-'+message.inboundProperties.timestamp]" storePrefix="prefix" doc:name="Idempotent Message">
    <simple-text-file-store name="uniqueProcessedMessages" directory="C:\yourDirectory"/>
</idempotent-message-filter>
```

Only new or modified files for the purposes of my process would pass through. However Idempotent Secure Hash Message Filter should do a better job at identifying different files.